# dose I call imagePipeline.prefetchToDiskCache multiple times will download multiple times?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, fresco

If I call `imagePipeline.prefetchToDiskCache` multiple times, dose fresco download image multiple times? the scene is I use fresco in recycler view, and I prefetch image when recycler view bind view. For one view recycler view will bind it multi times when its need, so shold I can call `imagePipeline.prefetchToDiskCache` safely? or is there some method to check the image url has cache or not (memory cache or disk cache both ok)?

Answer (score 1):

Multiple prefetch calls will not download the image multiple times. You do not need to manually check if the image is already in cache.

However, there is some computational overhead if you send multiple prefetch requests since the cache has to be queried.